# If A is a finite set and B is an infinite set, then B\A is an infinite set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Prove:** If $A$ is a finite set and $B$ is an infinite set, then $B \setminus A$ is an infinite set.

I've tried proving the contrapositive, that if $B \setminus A$ is a finite set then $A$ is infinite or $B$ is finite, but I don't think this is the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

HINT: Let $C=A\cap B$. Then $C$ is finite, and $B=(B\setminus A)\cup C$. If $B\setminus A$ were finite, what would that tell you about $B$?

Comment: Oh I see. So if $B \setminus A$ is finite, and since $B \setminus A$ and $C$ are disjoint, then $B$ will have to be finite. $B$ must be infinite, thus this is a contradiction, so $B \setminus A$ is infinite.

Comment: @lithium123: Yep, you’ve got it.

Comment: I guess that you have to prove first that $C$ is finite.