# proving infinite set from a finite and infinite set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, infinite-groups

My question reads:

If A is finite and B is infinite, then B-A is infinite.

Comment: Contradiction would be the fastest. But either contradiction or  a direct proof take very little time.

Comment: **Hint:** Notice that $(A\cap B)\cup (B-A)=B$

Comment: Emm, if $X,Y$ are finite, is $X \cup Y$ finite?

Comment: @Sam By recognizing that $B$ can be partitioned into those things in $B$ which are in $A$ and those things in $B$ which aren't in $A$.

Comment: As an aside, this appeared already on this site [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1849121/if-a-is-a-finite-set-and-b-is-an-infinite-set-then-b-a-is-an-infinite-set?rq=1) among possibly other places.  The hint given there is essentially the same as mine and copper.hat's.  It is a good idea to search the site first before posting a duplicate question.

Comment: @JMoravitz  Oh I see. Sorry about the duplicated question.

Comment: There is the slight difficulty though in your attempt in your comment that $A$ is not necessarily a subset of $B$, so $A\cup (B-A)$ is not necessarily equal to $B$.  It could be that $A$ contains things that aren't in $B$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to prove it directly.

If $B$ is infinite, there is a injective function $\beta:\mathbb{N} \to B$.

Since $A$ is finite, there is some $N$ such that for $n > N$, $\beta(n) \notin A$.

Then the function $\beta'$ defined by $\beta'(n) = \beta(n+N)$
is an injective function $\beta':\mathbb{N} \to B\setminus A$,
and so $B\setminus A$ is infinite.